# GPS Locations only from network

Tags: android, networking, gps

I am getting locations from network only not gps.i need gps locations not network provider..but as i see in my logfile..i am only getting network location which are not accurate.so i need to have gps locations..please help me out where i am doing wrong.thanks in advance..

```
if(isNetworkEnabled)
{
    try
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0,
        ll = new LocationListener() {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
            {

                try {
                    location = loc;
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    logFile log=new logFile();

                    dt = location.getTime();
                    log.createFile("Location Changed NETWORK:"+latitude+""+longitude+"time:"+dt);
                                        setdateAndtime(dt);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String errMsg= e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage();
                    logFile log=new logFile();
                    log.createFile("Error in GPS TRACKER When Location Changed"+errMsg+"\n");
                }

            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                        Bundle extras) {}
        });

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            dt = location.getTime();
            setdateAndtime(dt);

            logFile log=new logFile();
            log.createFile("Location From NETWORK:" + latitude + " " + longitude +
                     "time:" + dt + ":" + location.getProvider() + location);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e+"Error MSg");
    }
}
if(isGPSEnabled)
{
    try
    {
        if (location != null) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0,
            ll = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
                {
                    try {
                        location = loc;
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        logFile log=new logFile();

                        dt = location.getTime();
                        log.createFile("Location Changed GPS:"+latitude+""+longitude+"time:"+dt);
                        setdateAndtime(dt);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        String errMsg= e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage();
                        logFile log=new logFile();
                        log.createFile("Error in GPS TRACKER When Location Changed"+errMsg+"\n");
                    }

                }

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                        Bundle extras) {}
            });

            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                dt = location.getTime();

                setdateAndtime(dt);

                logFile log=new logFile();
                log.createFile("Location From GPS:" + latitude + " " + longitude + 
                            "time:" + dt + ":" + location.getProvider() + location);
            }
```

Comment: You can use a service for GPS Enabling if disable and can use intent to enbale it. Network doesn't provide actual position. I recommend you to use GPS only. I am posting answer, use it accordingly

Comment: Look for my answer. Ask me for any problem

Answer (score 1):

Change order and conditions.

Your code is..

```
if (enable_network)
{
  // get location from network provider
}

if (enable_gps)
{
  // get location from gps provider
}
```

Your code always receive location from network provider(if it was on).

So, you should check gps provider condition first and check network provider next.

Change code like this

```
if (enable_gps)
{
  // get location from gps provider
}
else (enable_network)
{
  // get location from network provider
}
else
{
  // can not receive location data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I things your testing your application in the Indoor,As the GPS does not work in indoor and that why it is working with your network...try to check the application by moving outside...

Comment: no i gave this apk to my client and saved a txt file in sdcard from which provider it is taking..moved around 50km and am only getting network locations not gps as i can see in the txt file..am i doing wrong anywhere please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Avinash I believe you are from India. Why is that important? because in India even on outside **I was not able to get the location from GPS via `LocationManager`** I have ran so many tests on GPS from `LocationManager`. It seems to return location very rarely from GPS provider. 
**Solution** 
Use `LocationClient` (Google Play services) to retrieve the current location. Google play services are very accurate and retrieves location from Network, GPS and Wifi, If available.
And there are more chances that you can `Location`. [Follow this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: Thank you every one.its my mistake actually i am stopping gps everytime as it needs some time to activate gps to get locations.